# Is an open ball neighborhood equivalent to a set $V$ such as $p\in V°$ (modern definition of neighborhood) ? Stuck in the proof

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, neighbourhood

According to Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis, a neighborhood of $p\in (X, \rho)$ is simply an open ball centered at $p$, that is $ \mathfrak B_{\epsilon}(p) = \{ x\in X | \rho (x,p) < \epsilon) \}$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.

According to a more modern definition a neighborhood is a set $V$ such that $p \in V°$ where $V°$ is for example defined as the greatest open set contained in $V$.

I am trying to decide whether this two definitions are equivalent in a metric space (($X,\rho)$).

---

- Assume a neighborhood of $p$ is a set $V$ such that $p\in V°$.

Then, $\mathfrak B_{\epsilon}(p) = \mathfrak B_{\epsilon}(p) °$ contains $p$.

- Now, assume a neighborhood of $p$ is a set of the form $\mathfrak B_{\epsilon}(p)$.

Then, one can clearly see that a set $V$ such that $p\in V°$ cannot be of the form $\mathfrak B_{\epsilon}(p)$ in general. (Note that we can find an $\mathfrak B_{\epsilon}(p)$ that contain $p$ however).

---

I don't really understand:

- if the two definitions are not equivalent then how can Rudin establish all his analysis results without any problem using his $\mathfrak B_{\epsilon}(p)$ definition ?
- If the two definitions are equivalent, I don't know how to go any further in my above attempt of proof. How can a set $V$ such as $p\in V°$ be an open ball centered at $p$ in general ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Aa you have said any ball is a "modern neighborhood" , while for any $V$ such that $p\in V^°$ then there must be some ball $p\in B \subseteq V$ so there's no generality lost by assuming all neighborhoods are open balls.

Comment: The definitions are *not* equivalent.

Comment: @Fzan so there is no loss of generality between them. Do you know what is the name for when two definitions do not loose generality one with the other ?

Comment: I am a bit intrigued by the fact that they are not equivalent but do not loose generality one with the other however.

Comment: Let $M$ be a metric space, let $p\in M$ and let $V$ be a subset of $M$. Then $V$ is a neighborhood of $p$ in the “modern” sense if and only if $V$ contains a neighborhood in the sense of Rudin. Using this, it is easy to translate statements concerning neighborhoods in one sense into statements concerning neighborhoods in the other sense.

Comment: Say you want to prove some set $V$ is a neighborhood of some point $p$, then the distinction between the definition does matter. On the other hand if you are given in some argument some neighborhood $V$ of $p$ then you are also given some ball $p\in B$ and this case the distinction between the definitions doesn't matter. It's more common to find the latter sort of argument in metric spaces. If you are still confused try going over some of the theorems and proofs and repeat the arguments but with the modern definitions.

Comment: *Do you know what is the name for when two definitions do not loose generality one with the other ?* Aside from the "do not lose generality" aspect (which has to do with specific uses of the notion and not the notion itself, and thus not really relevant to what one would call the notion), the term **spherical neighborhood** is a commonly used term for the notion. Of possible interest are these two sci.math posts -- [18 September 2006](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/XDqhJxpURJM/m/oXjWQxoVFyIJ) and [9 December 2006](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/99aKVXkIZeQ/m/7VpeQMdtHDoJ).